# Mirroring of a server

Tags: rsync, scp

I got 3 Ubuntu servers with database, Apache and php with some modules installed on each. Now my client changed the plan of using 2 servers as front-end i.e.,(load balancer will be used but not yet) and the remaining server as back-end. Now he said that he will be installing (basically web-scripts) everything on one server. Once everything is working fine. He wants me to clone everything on to the other front-end server by mirror-setup. Is copying via scp or rsync of those webscripts to my another server is sufficient?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Clone with `rsync` is easy:

```
rsync -av --delete <login>@<server>:/<remote-path> <local-path>
```

or

```
rsync -av --delete <local-path> <login>@<server>:/<remote-path>
```

BTW: Do you have thought about a version control system (SVN, GIT, etc.) as an alternative?